# Who's the user that executed Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I need to include information about the user that executed Jenkins job inside JAR Manifest among other things
What variable I need to read it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query Jenkins via its api. See `http://[jenkins-host]/api` or `https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API` for help. The information you need is contained there.

To get a feel for it, enter `http://[jenkins-host]/api/xml?depth=2` and search for "started by" on the page (make sure set the depth to at least 2).

You will need to get that information via a script in your build and then parse it based on the build id.

There already exists Python wrapper for that sort of thing: http://packages.python.org/python-jenkins/

Here's also an XPath expression that will parse out the "started by..." info by BUILD_ID:

`http://[jenkins-host]/api/xml?depth=2&xpath=//build/id[text()='BUILD_ID']/../action/cause/shortDescription/text()`

(Of course, you need to specify the actual BUILD_ID string).

Comment: Please don't circumvent the posting rules. They're there for a reason. If Stack Overflow won't let you do something, **don't do it**.

Answer (score 1):

Information about the user who started the build seems unavailable through [environment variables set by Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables).